# "I attend drawing class on Saturdays" vs. "I attend a drawing class on Saturdays"

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles, zero-article

I have recently been confronted with four statements about a child who has regularly (over more than a year) attended a drawing class (only one class) on Saturdays.

> 1. - I attend drawing class on Saturdays.
>    - I attend a drawing class on Saturdays.
> 2. - I regularly attend a drawing class.
>    - I regularly attend drawing class.

Obviously, they are rather similar, and I'm not sure which one is preferred. 
Which one(s) of the four are correct?

Comment: All the examples are fine.

Comment: You could even take drawing classes Saturdays and Sundays too if you’d like.

Comment: Remove ambiguity by adding **the** or **my** between the words 'attend' and 'drawing' for the sentence "I attend drawing class on Saturdays."

Answer (score 2):

Some references are the generic, well-understood name of classes.  Examples are Tennis or swimming classes.  It would be more common to refer to these without an article.  But "drawing class" is less common and probably much more specific instruction, and so would be more apt to be referred to as "a drawing class".

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a bit of a context dependency.  If you were telling someone that you couldn't go to a party you say it was "because I attend a drawing class on Saturdays" (or possibly "because I have a drawing class on Saturdays").  If you were giving someone your weekly schedule -- you go to the gym Tuesday and Thursday mornings and you "attend drawing class on Saturdays".

But there's likely a US/Canadian/Brit split as well.  I've noted for instance that Canadians and Brits are apt to say, eg, someone "attends university", but to the US ear that sounds like "a" has been omitted.

An example from the [BBC web site 9/28/2014](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-29381976):

*... a spokesman ... told the Associated Press news agency the 36-year-old man suspected of lighting the fire had been taken to hospital.*

In the US he would have been *taken to a hospital* or *taken to the hospital*.

Answer (score 2):

My circles of friends over the years, and my English instructors would be nearly unanimous in accepting all four as equally valid in the absence of any other context.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned that you could even take drawing classes Saturdays and Sundays too if you’d like.  When you say that, though, it does raise the question whether those are two different classes or the same one held on different days of the week.

Another way of phrasing this it to  pull the weekday out in front. Perhaps more than in the original version, this order could potentially introduce another form of ambiguity is you aren’t careful:

- Saturday I go to drawing class.

In the real world, the broader surrounding context of the situation would rarely leave room for doubt, but a sentence like that in isolation may be read in  two different ways: it could be repetitive, or it could be just one instance.

To choose between those possibilities, select one of these:

1. **This** Saturday I go to drawing class.
2. Saturday**s** I go to drawing class.

The version using *Saturdays* in the plural is the repetitive version that happens over and over, while the one with *this* is front of it is for just one particular day, saying nothing about whether you might do so next Saturday as well.

Those are both interesting in that they each use the present tense in a different and special way compared with the simplest way the present tense is normally used in English:

1. The first uses the present tense to indicate a habitual action.
2. The second uses the present tense to refer to an event in the future without resorting to a modal auxiliary or a periphrastic phrase.

Comment: "Saturday I go to drawing class" - is this a grammatically correct sentence? I don't think so. What is 'Saturday'? If you want to specify time you can have either "Saturday. ...", but this will most likely need a present continuous case, or "On Saturday ...".

Comment: Also I am still inclined to using indefinite article 'a' with the word 'class' in this sentence, even if we consider 'class' as a collective noun representing a series of lessons (which is usually the case), it still needs 'a'. So I vote for "I have a drawing class this Saturday" or "I have a drawing class on Saturdays".

Comment: @ArsenY.M. Yes, it certainly is a “grammatically correct” sentence.  It is using a day of the week as an adverbial phrase without resorting to a preposition.  It works just like *today* does. *Saturday* and the plural *Saturdays* both do the same, but one is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think class falls under any of the rule for not putting an article before a noun, thus, it should be "attend a class", "attend a drawing class". Only if you put it in plural you should not add anything - "attend drawing classes".

Comment: Not true.  He has gym class every other day.

Comment: @Jim, do you have a reliable source of proof of your example being grammatically correct. I don't know all the rules, but my intuition tells me it's wrong.

Comment: I can assure you it is a commonly used expression. How do you derive your intuition?  What is your background and experience with English language and usage (the concept, not the website)?  Woul you think it odd if the following conversation took place?  "Hey you should come to my game on Wednesday." "When on Wednesday?" "It's at 2:00pm"  "Oh, I can't go then, I have class from 1:00 - 3:00 on Wednesdays."

Comment: No, I would still disagree. I studied English for several years, but I do not consider myself proficient enough to argue, that's why I emphasized 'intuition', and that's why I cannot state that your last example is wrong as well.